# how to read status registers of a printer in qnx

Tags: qnx, parallel-port

i am using an x86 processor.
the interface used to connect to the printer is a usb parallel port ieee1284.

i can send data to the printer no problem.
i have tested it with the following command.

```
cat file.txt > /dev/usbpar0
```

i have read on several forums that there is no base address for a usb parallel port.
what would be the easiest way of reading the status of the printer. 
I need to know if it is out of paper or there is a paper jam. that is why i need to read the status registers.

I have included the source code i have tried to copy from [here][1]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

#include "stdlib.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "sys/io.h"

#include <hw/inout.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>      /* open() */
#include <sys/types.h>      /* open() */
#include <sys/stat.h>       /* open() */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include "parport.h"
#include "ppdev.h"

#define DEVICE "/dev/usbpar0"

int write_data(int fd, unsigned char data);
int status_pins(int fd);

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct ppdev_frob_struct frob;
    int fd;
    int mode;

    if((fd=open(DEVICE, O_RDWR)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not open %s\n", DEVICE);
        return 10;
    }

    ThreadCtl(_NTO_TCTL_IO, 0);
status_pins(fd);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

/* trivial example how to write data */
int write_data(int fd, unsigned char data)
{
    return(ioctl(fd, PPWDATA, &data));
}

/* example how to read 8 bit from the data lines */
int read_data(int fd)
{
    int mode, res;
    unsigned char data;

    mode = IEEE1284_MODE_ECP;
    res=ioctl(fd, PPSETMODE, &mode);    /* ready to read ? */
    mode=255;
    res=ioctl(fd, PPDATADIR, &mode);    /* switch output driver off */
    printf("ready to read data !\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(10);
    res=ioctl(fd, PPRDATA, &data);  /* now fetch the data! */
    printf("data=%02x\n", data);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(10);
    data=0;
    res=ioctl(fd, PPDATADIR, data);
    return 0;
}

/* example how to read the status lines. */
int status_pins(int fd)
{
    int val;

    ioctl(fd, PPRSTATUS, &val);
    val^=PARPORT_STATUS_BUSY; /* /BUSY needs to get inverted */

    printf("BUSY  = %s\n",
        ((val & PARPORT_STATUS_BUSY)==PARPORT_STATUS_BUSY)?"HI":"LO");
    printf("ERROR  = %s\n",
        ((val & PARPORT_STATUS_ERROR)==PARPORT_STATUS_ERROR)?"HI":"LO");
    printf("SELECT = %s\n",
        ((val & PARPORT_STATUS_SELECT)==PARPORT_STATUS_SELECT)?"HI":"LO");
    printf("PAPEROUT = %s\n",
        ((val & PARPORT_STATUS_PAPEROUT)==PARPORT_STATUS_PAPEROUT)?"HI":"LO");
    printf("ACK = %s\n",
        ((val & PARPORT_STATUS_ACK)==PARPORT_STATUS_ACK)?"HI":"LO");
    return 0;
}

/* example how to use frob ... toggle STROBE on and off without messing
   around the other lines */
int strobe_blink(int fd)
{
    struct ppdev_frob_struct frob;

    frob.mask = PARPORT_CONTROL_STROBE; /* change only this pin ! */
    while(1) {
        frob.val = PARPORT_CONTROL_STROBE;  /* set STROBE ... */
        ioctl(fd, PPFCONTROL, &frob);
        usleep(500);
        frob.val = 0;               /* and clear again */
        ioctl(fd, PPFCONTROL, &frob);
        usleep(500);
    }
}
```

"parport.h"

```
    /* $Id: parport.h,v 1.1 1998/05/17 10:57:52 andrea Exp andrea $ */

    /*
     * Any part of this program may be used in documents licensed under
     * the GNU Free Documentation License, Version 1.1 or any later version
     * published by the Free Software Foundation.
     */

    #ifndef _PARPORT_H_
    #define _PARPORT_H_

    /* Start off with user-visible constants */

    /* Maximum of 16 ports per machine */
    #define PARPORT_MAX  16

    /* Magic numbers */
    #define PARPORT_IRQ_NONE  -1
    #define PARPORT_DMA_NONE  -1
    #define PARPORT_IRQ_AUTO  -2
    #define PARPORT_DMA_AUTO  -2
    #define PARPORT_DMA_NOFIFO -3
    #define PARPORT_DISABLE   -2
    #define PARPORT_IRQ_PROBEONLY -3
    #define PARPORT_IOHI_AUTO -1

    #define PARPORT_CONTROL_STROBE    0x1
    #define PARPORT_CONTROL_AUTOFD    0x2
    #define PARPORT_CONTROL_INIT      0x4
    #define PARPORT_CONTROL_SELECT    0x8

    #define PARPORT_STATUS_ERROR      0x8
    #define PARPORT_STATUS_SELECT     0x10
    #define PARPORT_STATUS_PAPEROUT   0x20
    #define PARPORT_STATUS_ACK        0x40
    #define PARPORT_STATUS_BUSY       0x80

    /* Type classes for Plug-and-Play probe.  */
    typedef enum {
        PARPORT_CLASS_LEGACY = 0,       /* Non-IEEE1284 device */
        PARPORT_CLASS_PRINTER,
        PARPORT_CLASS_MODEM,
        PARPORT_CLASS_NET,
        PARPORT_CLASS_HDC,              /* Hard disk controller */
        PARPORT_CLASS_PCMCIA,
        PARPORT_CLASS_MEDIA,            /* Multimedia device */
        PARPORT_CLASS_FDC,              /* Floppy disk controller */
        PARPORT_CLASS_PORTS,
        PARPORT_CLASS_SCANNER,
        PARPORT_CLASS_DIGCAM,
        PARPORT_CLASS_OTHER,            /* Anything else */
        PARPORT_CLASS_UNSPEC,           /* No CLS field in ID */
        PARPORT_CLASS_SCSIADAPTER
    } parport_device_class;

    /* The "modes" entry in parport is a bit field representing the
       capabilities of the hardware. */
    #define PARPORT_MODE_PCSPP  (1<<0) /* IBM PC registers available. */
    #define PARPORT_MODE_TRISTATE   (1<<1) /* Can tristate. */
    #define PARPORT_MODE_EPP    (1<<2) /* Hardware EPP. */
    #define PARPORT_MODE_ECP    (1<<3) /* Hardware ECP. */
    #define PARPORT_MODE_COMPAT (1<<4) /* Hardware 'printer protocol'. */
    #define PARPORT_MODE_DMA    (1<<5) /* Hardware can DMA. */
    #define PARPORT_MODE_SAFEININT  (1<<6) /* SPP registers accessible in IRQ. */

    /* IEEE1284 modes:
       Nibble mode, byte mode, ECP, ECPRLE and EPP are their own
       'extensibility request' values.  Others are special.
       'Real' ECP modes must have the IEEE1284_MODE_ECP bit set.  */
    #define IEEE1284_MODE_NIBBLE             0
    #define IEEE1284_MODE_BYTE              (1<<0)
    #define IEEE1284_MODE_COMPAT            (1<<8)
    #define IEEE1284_MODE_BECP              (1<<9) /* Bounded ECP mode */
    #define IEEE1284_MODE_ECP               (1<<4)
    #define IEEE1284_MODE_ECPRLE            (IEEE1284_MODE_ECP | (1<<5))
    #define IEEE1284_MODE_ECPSWE            (1<<10) /* Software-emulated */
    #define IEEE1284_MODE_EPP               (1<<6)
    #define IEEE1284_MODE_EPPSL             (1<<11) /* EPP 1.7 */
    #define IEEE1284_MODE_EPPSWE            (1<<12) /* Software-emulated */
    #define IEEE1284_DEVICEID               (1<<2)  /* This is a flag */
    #define IEEE1284_EXT_LINK               (1<<14) /* This flag causes the
                             * extensibility link to
                             * be requested, using
                             * bits 0-6. */

    /* For the benefit of parport_read/write, you can use these with
     * parport_negotiate to use address operations.  They have no effect
     * other than to make parport_read/write use address transfers. */
    #define IEEE1284_ADDR           (1<<13) /* This is a flag */
    #define IEEE1284_DATA            0  /* So is this */

    /* Flags for block transfer operations. */
    #define PARPORT_EPP_FAST        (1<<0) /* Unreliable counts. */
    #define PARPORT_W91284PIC       (1<<1) /* have a Warp9 w91284pic in the device */

    /* The rest is for the kernel only */
    #endif /* _PARPORT_H_ */
```

"ppdev.h"

```
/*
 * linux/include/linux/ppdev.h
 *
 * User-space parallel port device driver (header file).
 *
 * Copyright (C) 1998-9 Tim Waugh <tim@cyberelk.demon.co.uk>
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
 * as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version
 * 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * Added PPGETTIME/PPSETTIME, Fred Barnes, 1999
 * Added PPGETMODES/PPGETMODE/PPGETPHASE, Fred Barnes <frmb2@ukc.ac.uk>, 03/01/2001
 */

#define PP_IOCTL    'p'

/* Set mode for read/write (e.g. IEEE1284_MODE_EPP) */
#define PPSETMODE   _IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x80, int)

/* Read status */
#define PPRSTATUS   _IOR(PP_IOCTL, 0x81, unsigned char)
#define PPWSTATUS   OBSOLETE__IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x82, unsigned char)

/* Read/write control */
#define PPRCONTROL  _IOR(PP_IOCTL, 0x83, unsigned char)
#define PPWCONTROL  _IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x84, unsigned char)

struct ppdev_frob_struct {
    unsigned char mask;
    unsigned char val;
};
#define PPFCONTROL      _IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x8e, struct ppdev_frob_struct)

/* Read/write data */
#define PPRDATA     _IOR(PP_IOCTL, 0x85, unsigned char)
#define PPWDATA     _IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x86, unsigned char)

/* Read/write econtrol (not used) */
#define PPRECONTROL OBSOLETE__IOR(PP_IOCTL, 0x87, unsigned char)
#define PPWECONTROL OBSOLETE__IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x88, unsigned char)

/* Read/write FIFO (not used) */
#define PPRFIFO     OBSOLETE__IOR(PP_IOCTL, 0x89, unsigned char)
#define PPWFIFO     OBSOLETE__IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x8a, unsigned char)

/* Claim the port to start using it */
#define PPCLAIM     _IO(PP_IOCTL, 0x8b)

/* Release the port when you aren't using it */
#define PPRELEASE   _IO(PP_IOCTL, 0x8c)

/* Yield the port (release it if another driver is waiting,
 * then reclaim) */
#define PPYIELD     _IO(PP_IOCTL, 0x8d)

/* Register device exclusively (must be before PPCLAIM). */
#define PPEXCL      _IO(PP_IOCTL, 0x8f)

/* Data line direction: non-zero for input mode. */
#define PPDATADIR   _IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x90, int)

/* Negotiate a particular IEEE 1284 mode. */
#define PPNEGOT     _IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x91, int)

/* Set control lines when an interrupt occurs. */
#define PPWCTLONIRQ _IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x92, unsigned char)

/* Clear (and return) interrupt count. */
#define PPCLRIRQ    _IOR(PP_IOCTL, 0x93, int)

/* Set the IEEE 1284 phase that we're in (e.g. IEEE1284_PH_FWD_IDLE) */
#define PPSETPHASE  _IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x94, int)

/* Set and get port timeout (struct timeval's) */
#define PPGETTIME   _IOR(PP_IOCTL, 0x95, struct timeval)
#define PPSETTIME   _IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x96, struct timeval)

/* Get available modes (what the hardware can do) */
#define PPGETMODES  _IOR(PP_IOCTL, 0x97, unsigned int)

/* Get the current mode and phaze */
#define PPGETMODE   _IOR(PP_IOCTL, 0x98, int)
#define PPGETPHASE  _IOR(PP_IOCTL, 0x99, int)

/* get/set flags */
#define PPGETFLAGS  _IOR(PP_IOCTL, 0x9a, int)
#define PPSETFLAGS  _IOW(PP_IOCTL, 0x9b, int)

/* flags visible to the world */
#define PP_FASTWRITE    (1<<2)
#define PP_FASTREAD (1<<3)
#define PP_W91284PIC    (1<<4)

/* only masks user-visible flags */
#define PP_FLAGMASK (PP_FASTWRITE | PP_FASTREAD | PP_W91284PIC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my problem by using the devctl command. i could read the status of the printer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <devctl.h>
#include <sys/dcmd_chr.h>

#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

#include "stdlib.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "sys/io.h"

#include <hw/inout.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>      /* open() */
#include <sys/types.h>      /* open() */
#include <sys/stat.h>       /* open() */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include "parport.h"
#include "ppdev.h"

#define DEVICE "/dev/usbpar0"

int status_pins(int fd);

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd;

    if((fd=open(DEVICE, O_RDWR)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not open %s\n", DEVICE);
        return 10;
    }

    // ThreadCtl(_NTO_TCTL_IO, 0);

    int data = 0, error;

    if (error = devctl (fd, DCMD_CHR_LINESTATUS, &data,
                          sizeof(data), NULL))
      {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error setting RTS: %s\n",
             strerror ( error ));
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      if (data & _LINESTATUS_PAR_NOERROR)
      {
          printf("No Error Detected!\n");
      }
      else
      {
          printf("Error Detected\n");
      }

      if (data & _LINESTATUS_PAR_PAPEROUT)
      {
          printf("Paper Empty\n");
      }
      else
      {
          printf("Paper OK!\n");
      }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```